# How to rotate a PDF by 45 degrees from command line?

Tags: pdf

Various tools (pdftk, qpdf, etc) can rotate PDF, but only with n*90 degree angles.

ImageMagick can also rotate pdf, but it automatically converts the vectorial format to a raster one, what I do not want.

Can I somehow rotate a PDF while preserve the vectorial format?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586726/rotating-a-pdf-file-by-n-degrees-where-n-is-not-a-multiple-of-90

Comment: (I think you mean normal degrees, not [grads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradian) )

Comment: @ilkkachu Right, thanks.

Comment: @A.B The Latex looks a fine solution to me, thanks. Someone could create an answer from it (I will do it if I have time).

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to convert the `pdf` to `svg`, then rotate the `svg` and finally convert the rotated `svg` back to `pdf`. For instance, assuming `input.pdf` contains only one page.

```bash
pdf2svg input.pdf tmp.svg
mogrify -rotate 45 tmp.svg
rsvg-convert -f pdf -o output.pdf tmp.svg
```

The `output.pdf` should contain the rotated vectorial image.

If `input.pdf` contains multiple pages, use `pdf2svg pdffile svgfile [page number]` to select the desired page.

`mogrify` is part of the [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) package, but please **DO NOT USE** ImageMagick `convert` to generate the output PDF, use `rsvg-convert` or `mutool` instead.